Where to place a dynamic load balancer for EV charger?
My electrician has recently installed my EV charger and added a wifi connected dynamic load balancer.
Inspecting the legacy electrical setup for my home, which has multiple central fuse boxes setup in different areas, I am not convinced that the installed load balancer is in the optimal position. As per instructions, the electrician has installed it in POSITION A, at the source of the 3-phase supply entering my home, i.e. effectively balancing the entire home use.
My question is that, based on the likely connected utilities to each fuse box, is POSITION B better?
It seems to me that is the likely location most likley to come under current overuse. My suggestion is to move the dynamic load balancer to POSITION B and configure it to balance a current of 40A at that point, rather than balance a current of 80A at source?

Edit
Following the answer this question is edited with more details. The "Fuse Boxed" are actually panel boards containing MCBs. The given Amps are the rated currents for those main MCBs. My calculations for the potential current load at LOCATION B is:

Oven rated max 3.7kW on 230V = max 16A

Oven rated max 1.9kW on 230V = max 8A

Gate opener max 0.7kW on 230V = max 3A

Washer max 0.8kW on 230V = max 4A

Dryer max 1kW on 230V = max 4A

Drying cupboard 1.5kW on 230V = max 6A

Dehumidifier 0.3kW on 230V = max 1A

Mountain heating compressor 3kW on 400V = max 7.5A

Mountain heating electric 3kW on 400V = max 7.5A

Lighting 0.4kW on 230V = max 2A

Power tools - ad hoc.

SUM: everything turned on: 59A + ?

EV Charger: ?



The issue is that the load balancer has multiple jobs.  It must not only limit current on the feeder to the basement fuse box, it must also limit current on the entire service.
Position B would only limit the other loads in the basement fuse box. It would be oblivious to loads in the other two boxes, and those, combined with the grid limit solely on the basement box, could overload the main supply.   Since you are in a 3-phase context, this overload could happen on any phase.
His installation, if it's setting a grid limit of 80 amps, is basically disregarding the current imbalances and defects in the existing system. He's like "I'm not touching that / not taking responsibility for that".  If for one would be happier to see the feeder to basement panel raised to 80A wire.
Your discussion of 3-phase power seems very confused and doesn't seem to realize what it does, how it works, or how it affects the wattage of appliances.  Unless these are three single-phase panels???
